# En que evento debo colocar este codigo

Tags: delphi

Tengo el siguiente codigo para operar campos de un TClientDataSet, el mismo tiene datos de un producto. el precio final surge de ese calculo. Los campos los muestro con un DBEdit cada uno. el precio tambien pero este se debe actualizar al modificar cualquier otro DBEdit asociado a un campo involucrado. A su vez se debe actualziar el precio en la bd por el resultado del calculo
Pero no se en que evento del formulario o del dataset colocar el codigo.

````
 precio:Double;
begin
with DataModule1 do
begin

precio:=cdsproductosCosto.AsFloat*(cdsproductosGanancia.AsFloat/100)+
cdsproductosCosto.AsFloat+cdsproductosRedondeo.AsFloat + (cdsproductosCosto.AsFloat * (cdsproductosImpuesto.AsFloat/100))+cdsproductosFlete.AsFloat;


end;```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios eventos que puedes usar en el TclientDataset.
Si es un campo definido como Calculado, puedes utilizar [el evento OnCalcFields](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnCalcFields).
Según la documentación:

```
Occurs when an application recalculates calculated fields.
```